# replace \n with " "

Tags: python, regex

Want to replace \n with ' ' if there is just 1 \n not where there is more than 1 \n

eg: `hi how are you\n\nhow you doing\nhow was your day`

I want output like this:

`hi how are you\n\nhow you doing how was your day`

I'm trying regex 
`re.sub(r'\n{1}',' ', text)`
but it's not working.

Comment: See @WictorStribiżew's answer below. Basically, you have to check to see whether the single newline `\n` is preceded or followed by another newline - necessitating the use of negative lookbehind (`(?<!\n)`) and negative lookahead (`(?!\n)`). Happily Python supports both. https://regex101.com/r/62RkEq/1

Comment: By the way, there is no difference between `\n{1}` and `\n` in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', text)
```

The `(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)` pattern matches an LF symbol if it is not preceded (`(?<!\n)`) nor followed (`(?!\n)`) with  a newline.

[image]

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qANIGi):

```
import re
text = "hi how are you\n\nhow you doing\nhow was your day"
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', text))
```

Output:

```
hi how are you

how you doing how was your day
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub()` directly, this allows you to specify a count:

`regex.sub('\n', text, 1)`

Comment: I want \n to replace with " ". In your regex what it would replace with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in other way!
Just split the text with \n, then concatenate the list with '\n' if any "" found. For each set of "" add one extra '\n'. For ex. 1 or 2 or any no. of continuous "" add 1+1 or 2+1 or n+1 no of '\n' while concatenate.

```
s=text.split('\n')
print(s)
a=''
c=False
for i in s:
    if i=='':
        if c:
            a+='\n\n'
        else:
            a+='\n'

    else:
        a+=' '+i
    c=i
print(a)
```